# tensorflow-gpu の導入がうまくいきません [RTX 3070]

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu

1. まずNVIDIAのドライバーをインストールしました（使用GPU: RTX 3070）
ドライバーの選択肢は１種類だったので、それをインストールしました

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 457.30       Driver Version: 457.30       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3070   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   46C    P8    17W / 220W |    951MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
```

2. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows を参照し、tensorflow-gpu, CUDA, cudnnのインストールを行いました
導入したバージョンは以下の通りです

- tensorflow-gpu : 2.3.0
- CUDA: 10.1
- cudnn : 対応表にはcudnnのバージョンは7.4となっていますが、10.1に対応する7.4のcudnnが無かったので、7.6.0をインストールしました

3. CUDAのbin, lib, include　及び　cudnnのbin, lib, includeに対してパスを通しました

以上の１～３を実行し

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

を実行した結果以下のような出力になりました

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 12021063292993637340,
 name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 15504652035085358081
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device",
 name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 3031884862663100678
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"]
```

nvidia-smi を実行してもpythonが実行プロセスに表示されないため、うまくいっていないと考えています。

Python のバージョンは3.8を使用しています。

もし解決策に心当たりがある方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いします

Comment: リンク先を確認したところ、windowsでのtensorflowのビルドのページでした。windowsでtensorflowをソースからビルドしたとの認識で良いでしょうか？

Comment: 特にビルドといった動作は行っていません、、、　インストールするだけで動くものだと思っていたのですが、見るサイト等間違えていますか？　もしくはビルドする方法等ご教授していただけると幸いです、、、

Comment: 質問中でのリンク先は merino さんが言う通りソースコードからビルドする手順になっています。pip 経由でインストールするなら https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip を参照してみてください。

Comment: tensorflow2系なら｢pip install  tensorflow｣でインストール出来ると思います。ただ質問者さんが実際に実行されたコマンドが不明なため、新しい仮想環境を作成してそこにインストールした方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: こんな記事を見つけました。11/06時点のRTX30xxではpip/condaインストールは出来ず、手動コンパイルかDockerコンテナが必要らしいです。[Install TensorFlow & PyTorch for the RTX 3090, 3080, 3070](https://lambdalabs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-and-pytorch-on-rtx-30-series/) あとこちらの Issue など [#44671](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44671), [#44678](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44678) ただしこちらの記事では何を指すか不明ですが「直接インストール」というので出来ているようです。[ディープラーニング関連ソフトウェア動作確認情報](https://www.pc-koubou.jp/pc/deep_learning_confirm.php)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
tensorflow-gpuのインストールは`pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0`
を用いました。
1点申しそびれていたのですが、使用環境にはAnacondaのJupyter notebookを使用しています。

Comment: Dockerを用いるということは、現在のRTX3000番台GPUはWindows上では動かすことができす（もしくは動作確認がされていない）、Linux環境が必要になるということでしょうか、、、？

Comment: 今のところはLinuxが必要な可能性が高そうですね。それとRTX3000系はCUDA 11.1とcuDNN 8.0.4が必要らしい記述をみつけました。[Geforce RTX 3090/3080/3070 について](https://www.gdep.co.jp/information/hot/geforce-rtx3090-3080-3070%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/), [NVIDIA Geforce RTX3080 / RTX3090ベンチマーク](https://www.gdep.co.jp/information/report/nvidia-rtx3080-rtx3090%e3%83%99%e3%83%b3%e3%83%81%e3%83%9e%e3%83%bc%e3%82%af/)

Comment: 有益な情報ありがとうございます。試しにCUDA 11.1とcudnn 8.0.4 と 8.0.5を試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした、、、　3000番台の動作環境が整うまではcpu動作で行う方が賢明なのではないかと考え始めました、、、

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のサイトの通りに導入を行うことで、GPU利用ができるようになりました。表記が英語であるため、簡単に手順を紹介します。ただし、対象はRTX 3000番シリーズのみです。

[RTX 3090 and Tensorflow for Windows 10 - step by step : tensorflow](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/jsalkw/rtx_3090_and_tensorflow_for_windows_10_step_by/)

**①**

- Python 3.8
- tf-nightly-gpu (2.5.0.dev20201120)
- CUDA 11.1
- cudnn 8.0.5 for CUDA 11.1
- Visual Studio 2019 (C++の環境)

をインストールします

**②** cudnn内の"lib", "include", "bin" をCUDA内にコピーします。その際上書きして大丈夫です。

**③** 以下のディレクトリにパスを通します。
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin`
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\libnvvp`
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64`
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\include`
ディレクトリ名は一例なので、各個人の構成に合わせて適宜変更してください

その後一度パソコンを再起動してください

ここまでで、起動後GPU認識ができた方は終了です。

**④** **私含め③までではGPUが認識されなかった人へ**
上の①～③を実行しただけではおそらく、GPU認識はうまくいきません。おそらく認識されなかった方はAnacondaの起動ログに`cusolver64_10.dll`が見つけられなったという旨のエラーが出ていると思います。
出ている方は

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1\bin
```

内の`cusolver64_11.dll`を`cusolver64_10.dll`に名称を変更してください。

以上で私は導入することができました。